# Unable to convert string into Integer or numeric type in Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I tried most of the general ways to convert list of columns into Integer type using spark API, but it's just not converting into numerical type

```
Input Schema:
root
 |-- customerID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SeniorCitizen: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Partner: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Dependents: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tenure: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PhoneService: string (nullable = true)
 |-- MultipleLines: string (nullable = true)
 |-- InternetService: string (nullable = true)
 |-- OnlineSecurity: string (nullable = true)
 |-- OnlineBackup: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DeviceProtection: string (nullable = true)
 |-- TechSupport: string (nullable = true)
 |-- StreamingTV: string (nullable = true)
 |-- StreamingMovies: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Contract: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PaperlessBilling: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PaymentMethod: string (nullable = true)
 |-- MonthlyCharges: string (nullable = true)
 |-- TotalCharges: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Churn: string (nullable = true)


df.select(*(col(c).cast(IntegerType()).alias(c) for c in df.columns))
df.printSchema()
```

But the output shows the same schema… Even I tried for a single column, but it didn't change the type

Any solution to this?

Comment: Assign your DataFrame with the variable `df` -> ```df = df.select(*(col(c).cast(IntegerType()).alias(c) for c in df.columns))```

Comment: Because `select` is a transformation which always returns new DataFrame.